# Using ZFTool in ZF2 to create new modules

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-tool

I installed the ZF2 skeleton application via composer and am learning ZF2 via the book Learn ZF2 by Slavey Karadzhov.  I added the zftool dependency via composer after the skeleton was installed. I'm on Windows 8.

I've been through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387615/how-do-you-add-zftool-to-an-existing-zf2-project-one-not-created-with-zftool which implies a requirement for application.config.php in the top level config which I have.

I've tried to create a new module via:

```
path/to/project> php vendor/bin/zf.php create module Test
```

Which returns:

```
SRC_DIR="pwd"
cd "dirname "$0""
cd "../zendframework/zftool"
BIN_TARGET="pwd/zf.php"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

The above is the contents of vendor/bin/zf.php

I've seen the same question asked on other forums but lacks answers. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows OS you need to run bat file:

```
path/to/project>vendor\bin\zf.php.bat
```

or if you want to use php script, run original one from library directory:

```
path/to/project>php vendor\zendframework\zftool\zf.php
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much, I'd lost hours trying to get zftool to run...